# Triggering UI elements from a script or commandline

Tags: python, scripting, command-line

Is it possible to trigger UI elements of addons through an external python script or a commandline option? To automate some processes of the add on without the need to reverse-engineer it.

Comment: why not just have your script trigger what the button in the addon would do?